# GWT compiler option to see generated files from custom generator with gwt maven plugin

Tags: java, gwt, code-generation, gwt-maven-plugin

[points out the -gen argument to compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975510/debug-view-source-of-gwt-generated-java-code)

As pointed out in the above post I added the gen flag by modifying my gwt maven plugin configuration like this

`<gen>genSource</gen>`

Funny thing it does write the generated classes but only the gwt core generator classes. none of my own custom generator classes output is written into it.

Any clues as to what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, I am assuming you are using Eclipse with GWT plugin. right click on Gwt project Run As->Run Configuration,

1. Select the "Java Application" on the left side. Right click on it,
   and select "New". This will create a new run configuration named
   "New    Configuration"
2. In the "New Configuration" ,you should be in the "Main" tab. Make
   sure that in the "Project" text box correct GWT project is selected.
   If not, you can select the right GWT project by clicking the "Browse"
   button next to it.
3. Also in the main tab, click on the "Search" button next to "Main
   Class" text box. Write "Compiler" in the popup window and select
   "**com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler**".
4. Go to the "Arguments" tab. Again you have two text boxes, program
   arguments (which are the GWT compiler arguments) and VM arguments.
   Put your GWT module name(eg.com.xyz.ModuleName) in the first line of
   your program argument box and in second line put **-gen
   destinationPath**(destinationPath is where you want to generate
   classes).
5. finally click on apply button and run the configuration.after
   finishing compilation refresh the project and check destination
   folder path you will get generated classes.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution -

the generated files incase of a maven based project are created in a hidden folder in target named .generated and contains all generated files. It was that simple. This solves the entire problem and now we are able to study and fix generator problems.

the gen tag in compiler configuration still doesn't work for my own custom generators and I haven't figured why.