# Duplicate source code from GWT generator

Tags: java, gwt, code-generation

I want to duplicate the generate code for debugging purpose from a GWT generator

I wrote this code in order to do this but it is not working :

```
printWriter = new PrintWriter(
    new TeeOutputStream(
        new WriterOutputStream(context.tryCreate(logger, packageName, className)),  // Main writer
        new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + className + ".java"))     // Debug writer
    )
);
```

The error from GWT is `Generator attempted to commit an unknown PrintWriter`

Any other way to do this?

Comment: Question is do you want to do that? If you want to have a look at the generated code, then pass `-gen` to the GWT Compiler (breakpoints might also work as I believe things a written to a StringWriter by default, so kept in memory)

Comment: Is it working with Dev Mode (super or classic) ? I can't make it working (tried `-gen E:\Test`, `-gen E:/Test` and `-gen Test` without success)

Comment: With SuperDevMode, generated files are available at `http://localhost:9876` (and through source maps in browser dev tools)

Comment: To see generated code this may help you [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892627/gwt-compiler-option-to-see-generated-files-from-custom-generator-with-gwt-maven/48220111#48220111)